# Multiple UIScrollviews at different speeds

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 4 UIScrollViews that overlay each other, and they all scroll when you drag a finger across. I however want to make one of them scroll at a different speed than the others.

I have tried using

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: (UIScrollView *)scrollView 
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating: (UIScrollView *)scrollView 
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging: (UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation: (UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

to capture when a scroll occurs but none of them are called during or after the scroll.

I have also tried setting the decelerationRate to be different for one of the views but they still all scroll at the same time?

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you make your class `UIScrollViewDelegate`?? and also assigned the delegate to `self`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess,you're not implementing  `UIScrollViewDelegate` method.

See the delegate property of UIScrollView.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate
```

and set it with the object of the class where you have implemented

```
UIScrollViewDelegate
```

methods,

```
myfirstScrollView.delegate = self;
mysecondScrollView.delegate = self;
.......
....
```

Comment: thanks for the response - i don't suppose you have a code example for this. I am not a true developer (a BA just filling a gap) so have been beating my head against the wall on how to get UIScrollViewDelegate working.

Comment: Cheers i hadn't added <UIScrollviewDelegate to the interface line of the header